# Get highest memory usage programmatically by iOS application using test cases

Tags: ios, swift, memory, memory-leaks, testcase

I am using following code to get memory usage by application in swift 5. But I want to display the highest memory used by application inside test cases and the result should be same as "memory result" inside debug navigator.

```
func memoryFootprint() -> Float? {
        let TASK_VM_INFO_COUNT = mach_msg_type_number_t(MemoryLayout<task_vm_info_data_t>.size / MemoryLayout<integer_t>.size)
        let TASK_VM_INFO_REV1_COUNT = mach_msg_type_number_t(MemoryLayout.offset(of: \task_vm_info_data_t.min_address)! / MemoryLayout<integer_t>.size)
        var info = task_vm_info_data_t()
        var count = TASK_VM_INFO_COUNT
        let kr = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &info) { infoPtr in
            infoPtr.withMemoryRebound(to: integer_t.self, capacity: Int(count)) { intPtr in
                task_info(mach_task_self_, task_flavor_t(TASK_VM_INFO), intPtr, &count)
            }
        }
        guard
            kr == KERN_SUCCESS,
            count >= TASK_VM_INFO_REV1_COUNT
        else { return nil }
        
        let usedBytes = Float(info.phys_footprint)
        let usedMegaBytes = Double(usedBytes) / 1024 / 1024
        return Float(usedMegaBytes)
    }

  func getContinousMomery() {
        let currentMemory = Memory.memoryFootprint()
        
        if currentMemory! > heighMemory! {
            heighMemory = currentMemory
        }
        print("Heighest memory usage is: \(String(describing: heighMemory))")
    }
```

I am able to get memory from above function inside test cases but not able to get accurate highest memory.

I tried calling function inside timer. But calling function inside timer in test cases not working as expected. I have schedule timer inside setUp() method, but setup method is called every time when new test case get called.

I want the way for getting highest memory programmatically.

Comment: Shouldn't you mock this to know what the correct result is for your test?

Comment: I have print the memory usage inside test cases and also check with memory result in debugger. but result is not matching.